# How do I place equation numbers before the equation in align environment?

Tags: equations, numbering, align

I am doing a proof homework that requires this special composition. The equation numbers need to come before the equation, i.e. on the left of the equation. It should look something like this:

[image]

However, this was achieved rather hacky using tabto package and is not referenced (all numbers are typed in manually). Therefore, I was thinking if there is a way to put the equation number before the equations on the left in `align` environment (or other similar environment for equations), so I could get automatic and referable equation numbers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That is the option `leqno` of your document class, if you use a standard one.